# Form is getting submitted upon error message

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am working on create album page and i want to add validation for album name. it should not be empty.
on click submit button i am calling validation function, that function throw the error message  but after clicking OK button the form got submitted.

i want to submit form if no error message are set, else want to redirected to same page

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to accomplish something like this is to run your validation function in the onsubmit atrribute of the form tag.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="text" name="album_name" id="album_name" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then your Javascript function should return false on error, or return true on success. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
  if($('#album_name').val() == '') {
    alert('Empty field'); 
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: And what happens if a user has Javascript deactivated?

Comment: Glad I could help. 

@Tim Then the separate back-end validation will produce an error. The OP asked for an onsubmit solution which doesn't allow the form to submit.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to set the validate-variable within your model like this:

```
# /app/models/album.php (or whatever you called your model)

var $validate = array(
    'albumname' => array(
        'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
        'required' => true
    )
);
```

This will make sure that your fields are getting validated by CakePHP and if the validation isn't passed you get redirected to the form without anything being saved.

Read more about validation in the Cookbook: [Data-Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1143/Data-Validation)